# Configure GitHub Pages syntax highlighting identical to GitHub

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

How to configure syntax highlighting for GitHub Pages to be identical to GitHub syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub uses a closed syntax highlighting library not available on GitHub Pages. Supposedly, it should be possible to get a reasonable result using the default Jekyll highlighter. However, for me it was simpler to switch to the highlight.js JS library. Here are the steps.

1. [Disable](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#syntax-highlighting) Jekyll's highlighter in the *_config.yml*
2. Obtain the *highlight.min.js* library

   - Prebuilt library is available from the [website or via CDNs](https://highlightjs.org/download).
   - A custom version can be [generated online](https://highlightjs.org/download), if necessary.
3. Obtain a CSS theme file
   Specific CSS theme can be picked chosen using online [demo service](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo). CSS files are also available via CDNs or can be downloaded for local access.
4. Load the library, theme file, and initialize the [library](https://highlightjs.org/usage)
   In my case, I placed the library in */assets/js/highlight.min.js* and included the following lines in */_includes/head_custom.html*

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/github.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ '/assets/js/highlight.min.js' | relative_url }}"></script>
  <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
```

I also included a CSS element */_sass/custom/custom.scss* in to overwrite code block background:

```css
.hljs {background: #fdfdfa !important;}
```